# Get index of closest value to x in an array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have an array looking like this (tho its a lot longer):

```
array ['0.2742330338168506' '0']
      ['0.28529288153011745' '0']
      ['0.28595917620794253' '1']
      ['0.2874392369724381' '2']
      ['0.316557712713994' '2']
      ['0.32113534393276466' '3']
      ['0.3231108855082745' '3']
      ['0.3163219663513872' '3']
```

and an array, `values`, which are the averages per value in the second column.

```
 values['0.282346788535' '0.296778235123' '0.303451234094' '0.31941237861']
```

For the first item in `values`, I want to find the index of the closest value in the other array's first column where the second column value is 0, for the second value in `values` the closest in the array where the value in the second column is 1, and so on.

Comment: Is efficiency a concern? How big are you array

Comment: @Reti43 yes, technologic english isn't great yet. For the first item in values array, i want to find the closest value in the other arrays first column where the second column value is 0, for the second value in values, the closest in the array where the value in the second column is 1 and so on

Comment: @PeterMølgaardPallesen the array is around 500 items long and it does function around 10 times so i think its not that important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code

```
a = np.array([[0.2742330338168506, 0],
      [0.28529288153011745, 0],
      [0.28595917620794253, 1],
      [0.2874392369724381, 2],
      [0.316557712713994, 2],
      [0.32113534393276466, 3],
      [0.3231108855082745, 3],
      [0.3163219663513872, 3]])
values = np.array([0.282346788535, 0.296778235123, 0.303451234094, 0.31941237861])

diff = np.abs(a[:,0,None] - values)
mask =  a[:,1,None] != np.arange(len(values))
diff[mask] = np.inf
idx = np.argmin(diff, axis=0)
```

Result

```
array([1, 2, 4, 5], dtype=int64)
```

---

Explanation

`diff` creates a matrix of the absolute difference between each element in `a[:,0]` and `values`.

```
array([[0.00811375, 0.0225452 , 0.0292182 , 0.04517934],
       [0.00294609, 0.01148535, 0.01815835, 0.0341195 ],
       [0.00361239, 0.01081906, 0.01749206, 0.0334532 ],
       [0.00509245, 0.009339  , 0.016012  , 0.03197314],
       [0.03421092, 0.01977948, 0.01310648, 0.00285467],
       [0.03878856, 0.02435711, 0.01768411, 0.00172297],
       [0.0407641 , 0.02633265, 0.01965965, 0.00369851],
       [0.03397518, 0.01954373, 0.01287073, 0.00309041]])
```

`mask` creates a matrix of similar shape where the values of the first column are `True` where `a[:,1] != 0`, the values of the second column where `a[:,1] != 1`, etc

```
array([[False,  True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True, False,  True],
       [ True,  True, False,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, False]])
```

By setting these values to infinity, we can focus on the relevant values per column to find the index of the minimum value with `np.argmin()`.

Comment: This helped alot, also great explanation!